# Query filtering on property with validator setted

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have model `User` and property `username` with validator which validates `username` for available chars, non-empty and *existence* in DB. So, I don't need any other checks when handling registration form for example - I just assign form's `username` value to model's property and catching validation error if entered `username` already exists...

But, it isn't work.

Because NDB validates property's comparison arguments too (see Property._comparison method in ndb/model.py) and it goes to endless reqursion in Query.filter(User.username == [somevalue]) and finally raises `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. NDB trying to validate [somevalue] with `validate_username` and go to this query again and again...

It's possible to assign username to entity's ID and use User.get_by_id(), but it's needed `username` to be changeable, so I need to use `Query.get()`.

So it is my `User` model:

```
class User(ndb.Model):

  def validate_username(self, value):

    value = str(value).strip()

    # Other useful checks - length, available symbols, etc

    if User.get_user(value):
        raise ValueError('Username already exists')

    return value

  @classmethod
  def get_user(cls, username):

    username = str(username)

    user_q = User.query()
    user_q = user_q.filter(User.username == username) # Here is the problem
    return user_q.get()

  username = ndb.StringProperty(validator=validate_username)
```

For example:

```
# Trying to add user, get RuntimeError exception
u = User()
u.username = 'John'
```

What I'm doing wrong? What's the best way to solve such problem?

**UPDATE to [Tim Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780524/query-filtering-on-property-with-validator-setted/15787150#15787150):**
Thanks. Yes, I've missed prop argument, but method received `prop` in `self` and `val` in `val` arguments - thus I didn't mention this mistake. But, you've missed the key issue - you don't use query with filter in validator (User.get_user method). Try this, there is no sense function or method validator is:

```
def validate_username2(prop, value):

    if User.get_user(value):
        raise Exception('User exists!')

    return value

class User(ndb.Model):

    def validate_username(self, value):

        if User.get_user(value):
            raise Exception('User exists!')

        return value

    @classmethod
    def get_user(self, username):
        user_q = User.query()
        user_q = user_q.filter(User.username == username)
        return user_q.get()

    # Try both please    
    username = ndb.StringProperty(validator=validate_username)
    #username = ndb.StringProperty(validator=validate_username2)
```

Comment: The docs say - Will be called with arguments (prop, value) and should either return the (possibly coerced) value or raise an exception.  However your validate_username method is only defined with value.  Try defining it as a function rather than a method with args (property, value).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you problem is due to incorrectly defining you validator as a method and not accepting the correct arguments.  See the quick example below, does work with filters.

```
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
dev~cash-drawer> def vla(prop,val):
...    if val == "X":
...      raise ValueError
...    return val
... 
dev~cash-drawer> 
dev~cash-drawer> 
dev~cash-drawer> class X(ndb.Model):
...    name = ndb.StringProperty(validator=vla)
... 
dev~cash-drawer> y = X()
dev~cash-drawer> y.name = "X"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1258, in __set__
    self._set_value(entity, value)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1004, in _set_value
    value = self._do_validate(value)
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 953, in _do_validate
    newvalue = self._validator(self, value)
  File "<console>", line 3, in vla
ValueError
dev~cash-drawer> y.name = "aaa"
dev~cash-drawer> y.put()
Key('X', 5060638606280884224)
dev~cash-drawer> z=X.query().filter(X.name == "aaa")
dev~cash-drawer> list(z)
[X(key=Key('X', 5060638606280884224), name=u'aaa')]

    dev~cash-drawer> z=X.query().filter(X.name == "X")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 859, in __eq__
        return self._comparison('=', value)
        File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 847, in _comparison
        value = self._do_validate(value)
         File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 953, in _do_validate
        newvalue = self._validator(self, value)
         File "<console>", line 3, in vla
    ValueError
    dev~cash-drawer>
```

Comment: Yes, I've missed `prop` argument, but method received `prop` in `self` and `val` in `val` arguments - thus I didn't mention this mistake.

But, you've missed the key issue - you don't use query with filter in validator. Try this, there is no sense function or method validator is: [i've added code to main question, as comments break the lines]

Comment: Agreed, but if you look at my example I performing the query on a model that has a validator that works.
In fact I just run a test with example I provided and the validator does kick in on the query. So you can see above value error is raised if I query for something that doesn't pass the validator. Which does make sense, and in your case you validator is effecituvly calling itself, hence the recursion.   
I you ever tried to update the object you would also get an error as the validator would be run again and would fail.  I think you should use a factory method to create/check for duplicate

Comment: Yes, I understood your example and mine works similar until I add query.filter in validator. I can't understand one thing - why NDB validates values in equation operator? To not do query if value is knowingly incorrect?

Comment: Its not even getting as far as the query the validator is kicking in when constructing the arguments for the filter, and in side you validator you are effectively doing the same query hence recursion,  if you think about it, it makes sense to validate the input for a query with the validator - in theory such a value (an invalid  one ) should not exist, and the same machinary for the property definition is being used to define the query.

Comment: By the way, Tim, is there any way to access `user` model object from validator being invoked?

Comment: Not sure, and I think you should think things through before spending more time on it, remember what I said about edits.  The validator will run on any future put of the object, at that point you current validator will fail if the username is unchanged as the record does exist.  I personally wouldn't use a validator for this use case.  I would use a method to set username and validate , or create a custom property that has it's own specific validation.